# Form respond with an HTML email

Tags: php, javascript, forms, html, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a simple mobile site that have a registration form for Interest, based on 5 different choice the user will get a different email response with information about that product. The email needs to be in HTML format with formatting options for look and branding.

Is there a package or script available on the market that does this sort of functionality? If not can anyone give pointers on how to approach that? Thanks in advance

Best

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp is a good start

Comment: voting to close. Your question isn't programming related. Your final question puts you close, but it's entirely too broad. imho.

Comment: thanks Caleb, I'll have a look at that. Sorry you feel that way Shad, but it is programming related, asking for a package or script doesn't means it's a retail question.

Comment: Had a look at the mail() function, I have seen that already, what I'm looking for is to have some styling in the message. Would i need a different approach in that case? thanks

Comment: Just output HTML in your email as you would with any other text.

Comment: @JamesHay: This is not a very good idea. i.e. Images will not render properly in many email clients. Use MailChimp's templates.

Comment: I pretty sure MailChimp doesn't use a special language that has somehow gained more cross-compatibility than HTML. But yes MailChimp will make it far easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [MailChimp's Email Templates](https://github.com/mailchimp/Email-Blueprints/tree/master/templates). Getting mail to show up properly in email clients can be an annoying task. Mailchimp takes a lot of the labour out of this. Use inline styles.

Comment: good answer to a poor question.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I'll have a look at that. @Ben, seriously man, why do you feel the need to be grumpy?! there are 5 people who replied with helpful information, you'll be a far better person if you learn that from them.

Comment: @lyad - its nothing personal. i should have explained myself better, though. lots of people reply to these questions because it gets them easy reputation. a quick google search would have netted you mailchimp as the first result. a good question would be something like "why is my implementation of the mailchimp API not working?"

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer
is a php package that will allow you to send html email from your server, and send attachments.
[PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Comment: thanks mathius, having a look at the HPMailer now.

Answer (score 0):

To get some HTML output in there really easily, create a file called (for example) `email_template.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- ... you know how this goes -->
</html>
```

And then in your PHP script, use this

```
$html_body = include('path/to/email_template.html');
```

Voila - your HTML is all in `$html_body` now. You can add basic dynamic tags with `str_replace`:

```
$html_body = str_replace('{DATE}', date('jS F Y'), $html_body);
```

Which lets you put `{DATE}` into your `email_template.html` and have it insert the current date there.